# apply material theme to ngx-datatable in ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-datatable

I'm developing a mobile application using the lateat ionic. I've installed ngx-datatable with npm to display some data. The table is working but I'm not able to apply the style. Following the documentation I added this to my page scss:

```css
page-datapage{

  @import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css';
  @import '/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css';
  @import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css';

}
```

and this in my page template:

```html
  <ngx-datatable class="material"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns">
  </ngx-datatable>
```

The table appear and it is working (even the sorting is working) but the table is is not styled and no icon appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy **index.css**, **material.css** and **icon.css** to **src/assets** folder.

After copying, rename the files to **_index.scss**, **_material.scss** and **_icon.scss**

In your **app.scss** import the files as follows:

```
@import '../assets/index';
@import '../assets/material';
@import '../assets/icons';
```

Font: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1249#issuecomment-359629984